# Persuade by the induction of fear

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which has as its definition,

To persuade by the induction of fear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [coerce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coerce): To persuade someone to do something by force or threat.

Answer (score 3):

[Intimidate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intimidate) is probably the closest fit.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I had a link in my copy buffer as you edited that.  Quick work!

Comment: I was just adding it as an alternative to my own post in an edit having had a bout of tip-of-the-tongue syndrome, when your answer came through!

Answer (score -1):

If using formal language i would suggest Coerce informally i might use Bully

Comment: Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Support your answer with facts that show that it is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed.